Balancing when combining multiple datasets (balancing in a metastudy?)
There have been some detailed discussion of balancing the datasets in this community:
Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?
Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?
The main conclusion, it seems, is that unbalanced datasets are not a problem, as long as one uses appropriate measures (accuracy is bad, at least when used alone.)
Now, suppose I want to combine multiple datasets in order to train a binary classifier. Here balancing might involve not only the same number of positive and negative outcomes (class balancing), but also balancing the size of the datasets. As a traditional extreme example, let's say one of the datasets used contains 95% of the samples. Then classifier performing well on this dataset only would provide nearly 95% accuracy for all the datasets combined.
On the other hand, reducing all the datasets to the same size would mean throwing away lots of samples (or alternatively biasing the outcome by upsizing the smaller datasets, e.g., using SMOTE.)
What are the good practices for dealing with such a situation?

"accuracy is bad," this is not correct, whether accuracy is a good metric depend on the needs of the application, not the properties of the dataset, but you do need to keep in mind what it actually measures.  I would strongly advise against using SMOTE, the synthetic data are not from the same distribution as the originals unless you have a large sample already.  I would weight the datasets rather than resampling, but it is impossible to advise how without knowing more about the problem.

@DikranMarsupial thank you for your comments. Could you expand on what you mean by waiting? As far as I understand, waiting means tweaking the classification algorithm, which is not always an option. Or perhaps you mean waiting when evaluating performance - something like weighted accuracy: $acc=\sum_iacc_i n_i/n$?

Kolassa's argument is not that accuracy is a bad measure of performance when there is imbalance. His argument is that accuracy is a bad measure of performance whether the classes are balanced or not. $//$ I agree with @DikranMarsupial that accuracy is not necessarily bad when it really is what concerns you, but $1)$ I have my doubts about how often that is true $2)$ recognize that accuracy of, say, a logistic regression is nonsense, as accuracy requires a decision rule on top of the logistic regression predictions $3)$ accuracy does not give a comparison to a benchmark like $R^2$ does.

@Dave thanks for the clarification. The issue here is not accuracy - I am happy with using full confusion matrix in binary classification. The problem is with concatenating datasets of different size (assuming that each one is balanced.)

@Roger I mean weighting the patterns belonging to each dataset in the loss function used to train the model such that each dataset made an equal contribution (which would hint that each dataset was equally important).

@RogerV. Kolassa's argument is against threshold-based metrics, as they are not assessments of the raw model predictions; they require a decision rule on top of the raw model predictions, and that decision rule might be terrible despite the raw model predictions being pretty good. A confusion matrix requires a decision rule.

@Dave 1) agree, the point is you need to choose the performance metric according to the needs of the application, rather than blindly use whatever suits your preferences. 2) completely disagree, there is no reason not to use LR for tasks where accuracy actually is the key performance metric - it isn't nonsense, it is an indication of how well calibrated the 0.5 probability contour is. 3) it is if you use the Cohen's Kappa version, which is just an affine transform of accuracy, so it measures the same thing.

@Dave I am not sure whether this is a practical suggestion, provided that I have a generic black-box classifier, which usually learns a decision rule rather than probability.

"Kolassa's argument is against threshold-based metrics, as they are not assessments of the raw model predictions;" My argument is that if you need a hard decision for your application, then a metric that involves a threshold IS going to be relevant for your application, and ignoring it risks choosing a sub-optimal solution.  The probability estimates may not be good near the decision boundary, but good elsewhere (where they are not important).  This isn't one-size fits all and you shouldn't use only one performance metric, you need to choose them carefully and without pre-judging it.

FWIW I often use a threshold based metric (accuracy, balanced accuracy, expected loss if I know the misclassification costs), but I also use AUROC (measure of ranking) and Brier score or log-loss (calibration of probability estimates).  You need metrics that cover all aspects of model performance that are important for your application.  There is a danger though of throwing lots of metrics at the problem, you need to choose them carefully.  In my experience if you ask someone why F1 is relevant they often won't have a good justification other than that it is in the toolbox/blog article.

Why not to use SMOTE in particular https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585173/is-smote-any-good-at-creating-new-points?noredirect=1&lq=1

@DikranMarsupial Then your accuracy value applies to a two-stage pipeline: logistic regression (or whatever) > decision rule. It does not just apply to the logistic regression (or whatever) unless that "whatever" truly does give hard classifications. You get the distinction. Most people do not and just accept model.predict as if the predict method is an integral part of the model when it really uses a fairly thoughtless decision rule.

@Dave yes, quite often when (kernel) LR is a really good option, there are variable misclassification costs or you need a reject option or the operational class frequencies are not the same as the training set etc. and you probably don't want just the 0.5 threshold anyway.  Same is true for neural nets, but the probability estimate are often not well calibrated.  Thoughtlesness is exactly the problem, and I worry that the ubiquity of toolboxes makes it easier for people to run data through standardised "pipelines" without really thinking about or understanding what is actually going on.
